# How do you test chained function calls with sinon?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, typescript, sinon

The code I am testing is:

`obj.getTimeSent().getTime();`

where `obj.getTimeSent()` returns a Date and then `getTime()` is called on that Date.

To stub this functionality, I tried this:

```
const timeStub = sandbox.stub(Obj, 'getTimeSent').callsFake(() => {
   return 1 //Doesn't matter what it returns
});
```

The [sinon documentation](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.0.0/stubs/) says that `callsFake()` "Makes the stub call the provided fakeFunction when invoked" but got an error "TypeError: obj.getTimeSent(...).getTime is not a function"

Comment: *but getTime() is still being called* - that's impossible, because it's not what a stub does. It will result in 'getTime is not a function' error but not in real getTime being called. Please, provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that can replicate the problem.

Comment: @estus you are correct, I wrongly assumed that the 'getTime is not a function' error meant that the function had attempted to be called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A function should return another function to chain:

```
const getTimeStub = sandbox.stub().returns(...);
const getTimeSentStub = sandbox.stub(obj, 'getTimeSent').returns({ getTime: getTimeStub });
```